# Which site can I ask CDN-related questions on?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I have several questions about CDN. Is there a site recommended for this?

I know the *[Networking Engineering](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/tour)* site is about *network* technologies, but the CDN is about an application layer network.

Comment: *What* kind of questions? Could you please share some examples?

Comment: The tag wiki has also ask guidance: https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/site-recommendation/info

Comment: @Glorfindel Such as, theory, how to set up(maybe any recommend open source  ), not about development.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include that information

Comment: Always check [the main search](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=CDN+application+layer+network), and the Help (on-topic), before asking; and since you have "several questions" include a few, or at least categorize the subject. --- Incomplete questions can at best get random quality answers. --- As you can see from the search (linked above) there's a few sites that *could* take certain questions, subject to the rules of each site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/) has a [cdn](/questions/tagged/cdn) tag that has [284 questions](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/cdn). Server Fault [accepts questions](https://serverfault.com/help/on-topic) about

> managing the hardware or software of servers, workstations, storage or networks

If your question is "which open source CDN do you recommend" that's not going to fly (sites generally don't do recommendations) but if you have a CDN and need to configure it then Server Fault would seem to be the place.